# Dpkg: error: too-long line or missing newline in ‘/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/aspell-autobuildhash’

Tags: apt, mount, dpkg

I am running Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on my Pi2. I think the power went off during an unattended-upgrade and now something is messed up with my system.

I first noticed that my NAS drive was not mounting at boot. Manually running the `mount` command I got:

```
~$ sudo mount -a
Child process terminated abnormally.
```

I then tried to re-install the cifs package and that's when I found that there's an error with dpkg:

```
dpkg: error: too-long line or missing newline in '/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/aspell-autobuildhash'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

This happens for any package that I try install or re-install. I am unsure what package is even causing this issue. How can I fix it ? Thanks.

Comment: You can see not fully installed packages by `dpkg -l  | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`

Comment: @nobody I get the same error.

Comment: Then show please `cat /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/aspell-autobuildhash` edit your question for that.

Comment: @nobody d09g02c2b8f732b041b2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh this stands in the file?

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/aspell-autobuildhash $HOME
```

Removes file in your home. We create a new one.

```
sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/aspell-autobuildhash
```

write content

```
dictionaries-common
```

then try

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install
```

Comment: I don't seem to be getting the dpkg error anymore but I still cannot mount my drives. I am still getting the error `~$ sudo mount -a` `Child process terminated abnormally.`

Comment: And yes, that string was in the file.

Comment: This was a question about dpkg error. Please make for your mount problem with your nas a new question. It would be a good idea to show `cat /etc/fstab` there. I think.

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought maybe the 2 problems are related. Is it ok to leave the file `aspell-autobuildhash` with `dictionaries-common` inside ?

Comment: yes. the content I copied from my xenial vbox.